# how to run 2 loop for servo motors in arduino code

Tags: loops, servo

I'm trying to make a project where two servos rotate at the same time. However, my code doesn't work.

```
#include <Servo.h>  

Servo servo1;  // servo control object
Servo servo2;

void setup()
{
    servo1.attach(10);
    servo2.attach(9);
}

void loop()
{
    int pos0,pos360,i;

    for(pos0=0,pos360=360,i=0;i<=360;pos0++,pos360--,i++){

        servo2.write(pos0);
        delay(20);
        servo1.write(pos360);
        delay(20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       #include <Servo.h>
     Servo ball1; //servo motor 1
     Servo ball2; //servo motor 2


     int i=100;
     int j=70;

     int w,e,k;

     void setup() {


       ball1.attach(3);  //attach
       ball2.attach(5);  //attach



     Serial.begin(9600);

     delay(1000);
      }


     void loop() {



     for(w=120,e=60,k=0;k<=60;w--,e++,k++)
     { 

        ball1.write(w);  //write
        ball2.write(e);  //write
        delay(15);
     }

     }
```

Comment: How does this answer your question?